# Android: Create a fragment with variable elements

Tags: android, button, scroll, fragment, android-linearlayout

I need to create dynamically a vertical linear layout inside a vertical scroll when I click on a button in the main activity. The linear layout must have as many rows as is indicated in an edit text of the main activity.

I now how to create the fragment with a linear layout and the scroll when the button is pressed, but I do not know how to fill this linear layout with buttons depending on the value of the edit text from main activity.

Graphical explanation:

[image]

I have this code:

```
public void onAdd(View view) { // This is the method called when button is clicked
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
    transaction.add(R.id.table2,fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

And this is the xml code of the fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.xxxxx.yyyyy.BlankFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- Buttons go here -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: It can be possible with ListView or RecyclerView. LinearLayout is just format of layout you need to implements list with custom adapter

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually adding views inside the LinearLayout, use a RecyclerView or a ListView and create a simple adapter that renders the views. After that, all you need to do is to update your adapter's items based on the user's input from the EditText.